Мне нужна помощь с python и pygame он долго считает столкновение с стенами
Когда персонаж проходит между узких стен, то он застревает углом
Вот код:
main.py
from fonts import *
from map import *

pygame.init()
press_e = False

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 800))


clock = pygame.time.Clock()
x, y = 100, 510
npc_talk = 0
main = True


while main:
    clock.tick(60)
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    for row in range(len(map_data)):
        for col in range(len(map_data[row])):
            if map_data[row][col] == 1:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), pygame.Rect(col * tile_size, row * th, tile_size, th))

    npc1_r = pygame.Rect((175, 175, 100, 100))
    npc1 = pygame.Rect((200, 200, 50, 50))
    pl = pygame.Rect((x - 10, y, 10, 50))
    pr = pygame.Rect((x + 50, y, 10, 50))
    pu = pygame.Rect((x, y - 10, 50, 10))
    pd = pygame.Rect((x, y + 50, 50, 10))
    #
    # # pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), pu)
    # # pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), pd)
    # # pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), pl)
    # # pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), pr)
    # # pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 255), npc1_r)
    #
    player_rect = pygame.Rect((x, y, 50, 50))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 255), npc1)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), player_rect)



    alls = pr.colliderect(npc1_r) or pu.colliderect(npc1_r) or pl.colliderect(npc1_r) or pd.colliderect(npc1_r)

    if npc_talk == 0:

        if not pu.collidelistall([pygame.Rect(col * tile_size, row * th, tile_size, th)
                                  for row in range(len(map_data))
                                  for col in range(len(map_data[row])) if map_data[row][col] == 1]):
            if keys[pygame.K_w]:
                if y >= 10 and not pu.colliderect(npc1):  # and pwcu
                    y2 = y + 10
                    y = y - 10

        if not pd.collidelistall([pygame.Rect(col * tile_size, row * th, tile_size, th)
                                  for row in range(len(map_data))
                                  for col in range(len(map_data[row])) if map_data[row][col] == 1]):
            if keys[pygame.K_s]:
                if y <= 690 and not pd.colliderect(npc1):  # and pwcd
                    y2 = y - 10
                    y = y + 10
        if not pl.collidelistall([pygame.Rect(col * tile_size, row * th, tile_size, th)
                                  for row in range(len(map_data))
                                  for col in range(len(map_data[row])) if map_data[row][col] == 1]):
            if keys[pygame.K_a]:
                if x >= 10 and not pl.colliderect(npc1):  # and pwcl
                    x2 = x + 10
                    x = x - 10
        if not pr.collidelistall([pygame.Rect(col * tile_size, row * th, tile_size, th)
                                  for row in range(len(map_data))
                                  for col in range(len(map_data[row])) if map_data[row][col] == 1]):
            if keys[pygame.K_d]:
                if x <= 890 and not pr.colliderect(npc1):  # and pwcr
                    x2 = x - 10
                    x = x + 10
    if npc_talk == 1:
        if alls:

            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (64, 61, 57), (0, 400, 1000, 400))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 255), (50, 420, 100, 100))

            screen.blit(npc_name1, (200, 420))
            screen.blit(npc_text, (200, 470))
            screen.blit(your_name, (200, 530))

        if not player_rect.colliderect(npc1_r):
            npc_talk = 0
    if player_rect.colliderect(npc1_r) and npc_talk == 0:
        screen.blit(talk, (x - 140, y + 20))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            main = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_e:
                npc_talk = not npc_talk
            if event.key == pygame.K_e:
                print(x, y)


    pygame.display.update()

map.py
map_data = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
]

tile_size = 50
th = 50

fonts.py
import pygame

pygame.init()

font1 = pygame.font.Font('fonts/font1.otf', 40)
font2 = pygame.font.Font('fonts/font1.otf', 20)
# font1 = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 40)
# font2 = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 20)

npc_name1 = font1.render("Джоунси:", True, (255, 255,255))
your_name= font1.render("Ты:", True, (255,255,255))
talk = font2.render('для разговора нажмите E', True, (255, 255, 255))
npc_text = font2.render('Привет, как дела?', True, (255, 255, 255))

